# Java Graphics not displaying changes

Tags: java, swing, layout, graphics

I'm working on a small Java applet, very much new to this programming thing. Using Java 1.6

I have a class that creates a `JPanel` of multiple checkboxes. The goal is to have the user select some fixed number of options, then pass those options to other methods

```
public class OptionSelector extends JPanel {

private JCheckBox[] optionCheckBoxes;
private int numberSelected;
private int goalNumber;
private ArrayList<String> selectedOptions = new ArrayList<String>();
private boolean rightAmountSelected;
private boolean isFinalChoice = false;
private DoneButton done = new DoneButton();

/**
 * This method is used only for the purposes of initialization
 *
 */
public OptionSelector()
{
    this(1, "test", "test");
}

public OptionSelector(int howManyToSelect, String ... options)
{
    super(new FlowLayout());
    JCheckBox option;
    optionCheckBoxes = new JCheckBox[options.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < options.length; i++)
    {
        option = new JCheckBox(options[i]);
        optionCheckBoxes[i] = option;
        add(option);
    }
    add(done);
    numberSelected = 0;
    goalNumber = howManyToSelect;
    rightAmountSelected = false;
}

public void setOptions(String ... options)
{
    this.removeAll();
    JCheckBox option;
    optionCheckBoxes = new JCheckBox[options.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < options.length; i++)
    {
        option = new JCheckBox(options[i]);
        optionCheckBoxes[i] = option;
        add(option);
        System.out.println(option.getBounds());
    }
    add(done);
    System.out.println(done.getBounds());
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    g.clearRect(0,0,this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
    for (int i = 0; i < getComponentCount(); i++)
    {
        System.out.println(this.getComponents()[i].getBounds());
    }
}
```

The applet that I used to test it is below

```
public class TestDisplay extends JApplet implements MouseListener{

OptionSelector s = new OptionSelector();

public void init()
{
    setSize(640,480);
    this.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
    addMouseListener(this);
    s.setBounds(10,10,200,200);
    add(s);
    s.repaint();
}

public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    s.repaint();
}

public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) 
{
    s.setOptions("1","2");
    repaint();
}

public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```

The problem is that when I test the applet, clicking the mouse changes the options just fine, but the new `JCheckBoxes` are not displayed. Experimenting with printing out the bounds of each component in the selector shows that the `JCheckBox` bounds are still stuck at (0,0,0,0), while the button's bounds have not changed. I've tried repainting the `OptionSelector` and the entire applet many times, but nothing seems to work. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You appear to be forgetting to call `revalidate()` on your JPanel container when removing and adding components:

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
  s.setOptions("1", "2");
  s.revalidate();
  repaint();
}
```

This is essential if you want the container (your JPanel) to layout the new components in the container appropriately.  Also, this is not a good thing to do:

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    s.repaint();
}
```

as you're overriding the paint method of a top-level component for no good reason and without calling the super method. Just get rid of that method.